# Why will this timer not execute within my Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

As the question states why is this timer not executing? I have it set up in a fragment and I have a feeling it has something to do with my runOnUiThread but I am not sure. Also i should add that I am not getting any errors or anything it just wont execute.

```
final WeakReference<Activity> activityRef = new WeakReference<Activity>((getActivity()));
    //creating timer
    public void startRandomButton(final ImageView img)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if(activityRef.get() == null)
                return;

                //activityRef.get().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            if(isAdded())
            {
                activityRef.get().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Activity activity = activityRef.get();
                        if (isAdded())
                            randomMovement(img);
                        else
                            Log.d("not added", "not added");
                    }
                });
            }
            else
                Log.d("Run on ui thread", "is null");
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Below is the entire fragment my problem is occuring when I create my timer. Like I said in the original question I am not sure what the problem is. The code compiles and executes just fine. The timer method just wont work though. I have my log cat tell me when an activity is destroyed or as you go through this youll see I have it tell me where things are null and I am not getting any errors. Help is greatly appreciated!:

```
package com.example.name.inserttitlename;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.InflateException;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import static android.R.attr.x;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class LevelOneFragment extends Fragment {

    //creating variables
    private ImageView img;
    private ViewGroup viewer;
    TextView textCount;
    Button failButton;
    Button beginButton;
    TextView countDownBeginText;
    private TextView countDownMain;
    public int scoreCounter;

    public LevelOneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

     @Override
     public void onAttach(Context context)
     {
       super.onAttach(context);
       Activity a;

       if(context instanceof Activity)
       {
          a=(Activity) context;
       }

     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }



    @Override
    public  View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment



        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_one, container, false);

        //creating viewables and such
        viewer = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.view_level);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        failButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.failureButton);
        countDownMain = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countDownMain);
        countDownBeginText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countDownBeginText);
        beginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.beginButton);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
        img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        img.setOnTouchListener(new LevelOneFragment.ChoiceTouchListener());

        //begin random movement

           startRandomButton(img);


        //setting up button for failure CORRECT TO TAKE YOU TO THE MAIN MENU
        failButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainMenu.class));
            }
        });


        //setting countdown text to 3
        countDownBeginText.setText(":3");

        //begin countdown from three
        beginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View beginT) {
                CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3*1000, 3) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        countDownBeginText.setText(":" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
                        //add possible sound here every tick
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        beginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        countDownBeginText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        //countdown from 60------- change parameters in count down timer to the time desired
                        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60*1000, 3) {
                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinishedMain) {

                                countDownMain.setText(":" + millisUntilFinishedMain/1000);
                                //add possible sound here every tick
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You lose", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //rest of text in method is trial

                                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainMenu.class ));

                            }
                        }.start();

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstatnceCState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstatnceCState);
    }

    //getting screen size
    public static Point getDisplaySize(@NonNull Context context){

        Point point = new Point();
        WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        manager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
        return point;
    }

    //randomly move

    public void randomMovement(ImageView img){

            int x = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(getActivity()).x);
            int y = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(getActivity()).y);
            img.setY(y);
            img.setX(x);


    }


    final WeakReference<Activity> activityRef = new WeakReference<Activity>((getActivity()));
    //creating timer
    public void startRandomButton(final ImageView img)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                if(activityRef.get() == null)
                    return;

                    //activityRef.get().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                if(isAdded())
                {
                    activityRef.get().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            Activity activity = activityRef.get();

                            if (isAdded())
                                randomMovement(img);
                            else
                                Log.d("not added", "not added");
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                    Log.d("Run on ui thread", "is null");
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

    //listener for the moving ball
    private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){

            //Calling Counter
            textCount = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textViewCount);



            //switch statement for different events
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //this is where youre going to generate randmom location with id.setX(randomX) and id.setY(randomY)
                    randomMovement(img);

                    //Setting Counter to count when img is clicked
                    String countValue = textCount.getText().toString();
                    scoreCounter = Integer.parseInt(countValue);
                    scoreCounter++;
                    textCount.setText(String.valueOf(scoreCounter));
                    break;


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;


            }



            //checking score
            if(scoreCounter == 10 )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You win", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            viewer.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a little bit clear what code also do you have in the rest of the class. So here is the code for the fragment:

```
public class someFragmentClass extends Fragment {

    Timer mTimer;
    View mView;

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                       randomMovement(img);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.someFragment, container, false);

       mTimer = new Timer();
       mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0 , 5000);

       return mView;
    }

}
```

I haven't tested the code so there could be subtle mistakes.

Comment: I can post the whole fragment if you would like me to.

Comment: @Cantum2 yes, please. Moreover, try to use provided code

Comment: Okay i just uploaded full fragment. While you go over that I will use your version and see how it does.

Comment: Just a small update. I implemented your timer and I am getting a null pointer exception on `mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 5000);`

Comment: also sorry if the code is kinda messy. When I figure this bug out im going through and cleaning it up.

Comment: @Cantum2 start the timer inside of overrided `onStart` method

Comment: You are the man!! Thank you so much that worked!. Can you explain to me why that is though?

Comment: @Cantum2 it's difficult to explain in two words. The main point of interest: `runOnUiThread`. Learn more about threads and AsyncTasks. In _my opinion_, if it's necessary to use `runOnUiThread` then there is a big chance that something wrong with your structure (logic) of code.

Comment: Awesome thank you for giving me something to look into. I had a feeling it was that. Thank you so much once again!